# Is there a way to add multiple strings to a stack without using a push method each time

Tags: java, stack

I am working on a program to help student learn all the presidents in order. I am using a stack. I want to create a stack with all of the presidents in order. Then the user will enter a president name and the program will compare there input with the top of the stack.

I want to know if there is a way to fill my stack with Strings without using the .push method 44 times?

Here is what I have so far in my main:

```
package namepresidents;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NamePresidents {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       BoundedStackInterface<String> presidents;
       presidents = new ArrayStack<String>(41);

       presidents.push("George Washington");

       String menu = "Would you like to study: \n"
                + "1. All the presidents \n"
                + "2. The first half \n"
                + "3. The second half \n"
                + "0. Exit \n";

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option = in.nextInt();  
    }

}
```

Here is my ArrayStack class for references:

```
package namepresidents;

public class ArrayStack<T> implements BoundedStackInterface<T> {
    protected final int DEFCAP= 43;
    protected T[] stack;  //holds stack of elemets
    protected int topIndex = -1;


    public ArrayStack(){                        // default constructor
        stack = (T[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
    }

    public ArrayStack(int maxSize){             // constructor with user defined array size
        stack = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
    }


    public void push(T element){
    //throws excption if the stack is full
    //otherwise places element on top of stack
        if (!isFull())
        {
            topIndex++;
            stack[topIndex] = element;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new StackOverflowException("Push attempted on a full stack.");
        }
    }
    public boolean isFull(){
           //returns true if the stack is full
        if (topIndex == stack.length-1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
           //returns true if the stack is empty
        if (topIndex == -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void pop(){
    //throws excption if the stack is full
    //otherwise places element on top of stack
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            stack[topIndex] = null;
            topIndex--;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new StackUnderflowException("Pop attempted on an empty stack.");
        }
    }
    public T top(){
    //throws excption if the stack is full
    //otherwise returns element on top of stack
        T topOfStack = null;
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            topOfStack = stack[topIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new StackUnderflowException("Top attempted on an empty stack.");
        }
        return topOfStack;
    }
}
```

Comment: What stops you from adding a method that pushes multiple items into the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Since the ArrayStack is a class that you implemented and it don't support that feature, your answer is no.

But you could add one push method to ArrayStack that accepte a list like this:

```
public void push(List<T> elements) {
    for(T element : elements) {
        push(element);
    }
}
```